# What did I do wrong solving $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2-\sqrt[6]{3x+64}}{5x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2-\sqrt[6]{3x+64}}{5x}$$

Without L'Hopital, I have decided to do this by variable substitution:

Let

$$w^6 = 3x+64$$

Which means that $w^6 = 64$ and also that $x\to 2$ in our new limit:

$$\lim_{w\to 2}\frac{2-\sqrt[6]{w^6}}{5x}$$

Which is

$$\lim_{w\to 2}\frac{2-w}{5x}$$

We can find the value of $x$:

$$w^6=3x+64 \implies x = \frac{w^6-64}{3}$$

So

$$\lim_{w\to 2}\frac{2-w}{5\left(\frac{w^6-64}{3}\right)}$$

Simplify

$$\lim_{w\to 2}\frac{2-w}{\left(\frac{5w^6-320}{3}\right)}$$

Which is

$$\lim_{w\to 2}\frac{3(2-w)}{5w^6-320}$$

Knowing that $(w-2)$ is one factor of $(5w^6-320)$, I can use synthetic division to factorize it. My result is this:

$$\lim_{w\to 2}\frac{3(2-w)}{(w-2)(5w^5+10w^4+20w^3+40w^2+80w)}$$

Cancel the $(2-w)$:

$$\lim_{w\to 2}\frac{-3}{(5w^5+10w^4+20w^3+40w^2+80w)}$$

If you evaluate this, you will get

$$\frac{-3}{800}$$

When it should be

$$\frac{-1}{320}$$

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: One thing that you did not so good is to multiply by $5$. That made it uglier. Note that $w^6-64=(w^3-8)(w^3+8)=(w-2)(w^2+2w+4)(w^3+8)$. Now cancel.

Comment: *What did I do wrong ?* - I don't know, and I don't care. Factor $2^6=64$ outside the radical sign, and then expand it into its [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) using $(1+t)^a\simeq1+at$ when $t\to0$. The result follows almost immediately.

Comment: @Lucian the factorization was missing a $160$ that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there'll be 160 added to the denominator. your division is not correct

Comment: Dang. By the time I did the division you had already posted! This does seem to be the source of the problem

Comment: This is it! Thank you..... it's the little things that mess everything up.

Comment: haha :) alright. my pleasure